# How to delete Jenkins Job automatically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

We are using Freestyle Jenkins for our internal work.

We used to create multiple Jobs for each flow of execution. We merged the flow number in Jenkins's job to avoid an override. Finally, we ends up creating lots of Jobs. So trying to figure out any automated way to delete the jobs once build is done?

I came through an option for deleting workspace only, not for full Jenkins's job.

Can anyone help me with tool, automation kind of thing to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this in freestyle projects, since I am not using them myself. But there is a way in declarative/scripted pipelines

```
def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("<folder>/<job>")
job.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using HTTP POST

```
http://<jenkins-Server-Url>/job/<your-Job-Name>/doDelete
```

Example:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/test0delete/doDelete"
```